# How to extend my display properly in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, display, external-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make apps launch on an external monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/214786/how-can-i-make-apps-launch-on-an-external-monitor)

I have an external monitor and I have extended the display.

Macbook = Right
External = Left

For some reason all of my apps show up on my macbook display. How can I have them appear on my external, and have my MacBook be the extended display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag the little graphical menu bar in the screen layout Pref Pane to your 2nd monitor.