# How can I make apps launch on an external monitor?

Tags: macos, display, external-display

How can I make my apps launch on an external monitor instead of on my MacBook's built-in monitor?

Comment: That worked perflectly! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System Preferences > Display > Arrangement Tab

Drag the menu bar (represented as stripe on one of the displays) to whichever screen you desire.

[image]